# Triggering Flyway migration before each test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, database-migration, flyway

I'm implementing an integration test suite in a Spring Boot project. My project is using Flyway for database migration.

My test class looks similar to this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Testcontainers
internal class MyIntegrationTest {
    @Container
    private val postgres = postgresContainer

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    // ... several test cases
}
```

Spring Boot runs Flyway migration at application context startup. The problem is that `@SpringBootTest` starts application context only once, so my DB is initialized only **before all tests** and not **before each test**.

I also tried injecting a Flyway field in my test class:

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var flyway: Flyway

@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
    flyway.migrate()
}
```

but there is `No qualifying bean of type 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' available`.

So, which is the right way to trigger migration before each test?

**NOTES**:

- (PostgreSQL) test container is correctly created and started for each single test.
- I'm using this config in application.properties: `spring.flyway.enabled=false`

Comment: Have a look at the [Flyway test extensions](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions)

Comment: Injecting a flyway field and running flyway.clean(), flyway.migrate() should work. Have you inspected why it can't find a qualifying bean?

Comment: @OnomeSotu, yes, you're right. I was using a wrong config for Flyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution thinkering with JUnit and Spring Boot configuration.

The reason for `No qualifying bean of type 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' available` was my wrong configuration: `spring.flyway.enabled=false`. This is disabling also the creation of a Flyway instance, not only the initial migration.

So I removed this property from `application.properties`, and added this code to my test class (as also suggested by *Onome Sotu* in his comment):

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var flyway: Flyway

@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
    flyway.clean()
    flyway.migrate()
}
```

I also added `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` to the test class: this way the container is created and started just once (no need to recreate the database from scratch now that I can clean it before each test). Additionally, this makes tests execution very faster.

**NOTE**: Actually, with this setup, container creation is executed twice: one at context startup and one on test class creation. Similarly, DB migration is executed for each test case +1 (the +1 happens at context startup). I'd like to find a way to disable unnecessary container creation and database migration)...

Answer (score 1):

Try annotating your tests like this:

```
@Test
@FlywayTest
public void testFunction(){..}
```

From Flyway documentation:

> Annotation FlywayTest for database unit testing. Use Flyway feature.
>
> ```
> clean - execution of flyway task clean
> init - execution of flyway task init
> migrate - execution of flyway task migrate
> ```

https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions

Also, make sure to include the following dependencies:

```
testCompile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.4.1'

testCompile 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions:flyway-spring-test:6.3.3'
```